# Not able to convert binary data from dicom file with python

Tags: python, binary, encode, dicom

I have a **Vector Grid Data** from a  **Deformable Registration Grid Sequence** whos type is binary.

i'm Trying to convert this data to a list of, i think, signed floating point value elements. but can find the function that allows me perform this operation. Let me show you a piece of the information.

b' dZ=\x00\x90\xb3=\x00\x18\x89\xbd \xe9}=\x00\xc0\xd6=\x00\xa0\xa5\xbd\xe0]\x93=\x00\x10\xfd=\x00\xa8\xc4\xbd\xc0\x8e\xa9=

...

\x95\xf9\xbb\xbc\x00\x80\x06=\xc6\x88(=\xa9\xcb\x82\xbc\x00@\xa6<A\xce\xc6<\xc5\xd5\x19\xbc\x00\x00\x0e<k\xba\x17<\x02\x07i\xbb'

i'll appreciate your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Vector Grid Data* consists of [triplets of 4 byte floating point values](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.20.3.html#sect_C.20.3.1.3). Try

```py
from struct import unpack

data = b"..."
values = unpack(f"<{len(data) / 4}f", data)
```